# Kubernetes : How to change service ports using patch

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Let be the following service :

```
serivce1.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service1
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
   - port: 90
     name: port0
     targetPort: 40000
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

I apply as follow : kubectl apply -f service1.yml

Now I want to change the ports section. I could edit the yml and apply again but I prefere to use patch :

```
kubectl patch service service1 -p '{"spec":{"ports": [{"port": 80,"name":"anotherportspec"}]}}'
service/service1 patched
```

but this command adds a new port and keeps the old one :

```
$ kubectl describe svc service1
Name:              service1
Namespace:         abdelghani
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=nginx
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Families:       <none>
IP:                10.98.186.21
IPs:               <none>
Port:              anotherportspec  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         10.39.0.3:80
Port:              port0  90/TCP
TargetPort:        40000/TCP
Endpoints:         10.39.0.3:40000
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

My question:
Is it possible to change the ports sections by replacing the old section with the one passed as parameter?

Thx

Comment: what happens if you pass the `port0` instead of `anotherportspec`? is it throwing an error?

Comment: yes. It throws an error : The Service “service1” is invalid: spec.ports[1].name: Duplicate value: “port0”

Comment: looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57707414/how-to-change-port-of-a-kubernetes-container-using-kubectl-patch

Comment: The problem may be in patch strategy - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/ . Can you try as an alternative use kubectl edit svc (i to insert propert port ESC :wq tosave changes)?

Comment: Editing the service YAML file (and committing it to source control) seems like a better and simpler approach to me?

Comment: Thx @Malgorzata. The problem is indeed in patch strategy. Using the type flag solved the problem : $ kubectl patch svc service1 --type merge -p '{"spec":{"ports": [{"port": 80,"name":"anotherportspec"}]}}'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As we've (with @Abdelghani) discussed the problem is  in patch strategy. Using following command:

`$ kubectl patch svc service1 --type merge -p '{"spec":{"ports": [{"port": 80,"name":"anotherportspec"}]}}'` solves the problem.

Flag `--type merge` will enable replace the existing values.

Read more: [kubectl-patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/).

As an alternative for patching you have couple options:

**1.**   Edit your service using `kubectl edit` command:
In prompt  `$ kubectl edit svc <service_name> -n <namespace>`

```
i - to edit the service

ESC, :wq - update your service
```

Paste proper port and save file.

**2.** You can also manually edit service conf file:

```
vi your-service.yaml
```

update port number and apply changes

```
$ kubectl apply -f your-service.yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI, when all else fails and you just need to get it done sed, awk, perl can help. here is an example of changing a service from ClusterIP to NodePort and using a specific port.

```
kubectl get service/kubernetes-dashboard -n kubernetes-dashboard -o yaml | sed -E "s/(targetPort:\s[0-9]{0,5})/\1\n\ \ \ \ nodePort: 32323/" | sed 's/type: ClusterIP/type: NodePort/' | kubectl replace -f -
```

*Please remember to make a quick backup first.